# ConfigurationManager - How to use connection strings with .NET 3.5?

Tags: c#, .net, configuration, connection-string

I see a very good post here about what I am wanting to do,

[.net 3.5: To read connectionstring from app.config?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1831291/net-3-5-to-read-connectionstring-from-app-config)

It says to use the ConfigurationManager class. I cannot reference the ConfigurationManager class.

If I look at the system.dll that I am using (which is v2.0.50727) there is no ConfigurationManager class.

I am using VS 2008, and my project is set to compile as .NET 3.5.

If I do this,

```
string test = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["test"];
```

I get the message 'Error    182 The type or namespace name 'ConfigurationManager' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Configuration' (are you missing an assembly reference?)'

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you added a reference to System.Configuration?

Comment: Right. I thought I had, but I was referencing the namespace 'System.Configuration' in the 'System' dll

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `ConfigurationManager` is part of the `System.Configuration` namespace. By default it is not referenced in the projects, so add a reference to if from the GAC.

Comment: Yep, as mentioned above I was referencing the namespace 'System.Configuration' in the 'System' dll

Answer (score 1):

You have reference the 'system.configuration.dll'

just right click in VS on the reference folder, and search this dll